# An established connection was aborted

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple example for socket but I'm receiving the message I wrote in the title.

The code I use is the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new Thread(() -> new Server()).start();

        try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2106))
        {
            try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))
            {
                try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in))
                {
                    while (in.hasNext())
                    {
                        out.writeUTF(in.nextLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static class Server
    {
        public Server()
        {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2106))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try (final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept())
                    {
                        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
                        {
                            System.out.println("IP: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has sent:" + in.readUTF());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The first message is transferring successfully, but when I try to type again in the console, I get the error. Any idea why this is happening? I tried google but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Comment: In your server while-loop, you only read one line of input.

Comment: @NomadMaker what you mean i only read one line of input? Can you explain better please?

Comment: Walk through your Server class. The only time you read from the Socket is not in a loop. So it only reads what data is there and available. You don't read any more data. So when the client tries to send more data, bad things happen. But in your client, you send multiple strings. Try rubber-duck debugging. This is when you go through your code line-by-line and try explaining to a rubber duck (or a puppy, or an infant, or an imaginary friend).

Comment: But i sent one String (every time i type using the opened `DataOutputStream`) and then i only read once the data using `in.readUTF()`. I don't see the 2nd time you claim. I tried do line by line.

Comment: In your client code (main) you have ``while (in.hasNext())`` and you read from System.in and write during this loop.

Comment: @NomadMaker first of all thanks for responding to me. Also the idea is to keep sending data as long as i write something without open new `Socket`. I tried use a `new DataOutputStream` on each word scanner get but it simply close socket automatically and i believe it's not the proper way. I'm sorry if i give you hard time i'm not that amateur as i look, is just when i get confused i'm losing it. The code looks fine in my eyes. `out.writeUTF();` is supposed to write/sent each time i write something in console.

Comment: In the server, you only read once per accept. You need to accept the socket, then have a new loop.

Comment: @NomadMaker the `static class Server` has the `final Socket socket` inside `while(true)` isnt this how its supposed to work cause accept() pause until a new socket connect.

Comment: Your server while-loop creates a new socket each time through the loop. The client however, keeps using the same socket (which is correct) to write in its loop. Please find a client/server tutorial.

Comment: @NomadMaker Ok i understood what you meant and it make sense but how i can adjust my code to send data each time i type from client without open new Socket?

Comment: First, keep using the same Socket and Stream for the single connection. Second, for each write you do from the client, you need a corresponding read from the server.